# Azure Pipelines denies access to folder "runtimes" when reading build artifacts for dotnet webapi

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two relatively simple pipelines, both running on `ubuntu-latest` Microsoft hosted agents:

Build:

1. Build dotnet api using `dotnet publish`
2. Build some other artifacts
3. Compress everything as a single zip file (not tar.gz) and publish that file as an artifact

Release:

1. Extract the artifact to the local working directory.
2. Compress the dotnet api folder.
3. Use the task `AzureWebApp@1` to deploy the api to an App Service.

My problem is that as soon as the release starts to read files from the working directory I get an "Access Denied" error. I eventually relaized that the `ExtractFiles@1` task does not grant any permissions at all to any files or folders when they are extracted so I need to set permissions manually:

```bash
chmod -R +r ./* $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

But apparently I'm not allowed to change permissions of the runtimes subfolders for some reason. Why would this be? I've verified that simply deleting the folder at build time allows `chmod` to work just fine.

```
chmod: cannot access '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app/runtimes/browser': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app/runtimes/win-arm': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app/runtimes/unix': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app/runtimes/win-x64': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app/runtimes/win-arm64': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app/runtimes/win-x86': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app/runtimes/win': Permission denied
```

As a potential workaround I'm considering just zipping the app folder content as well and directly deploying that. It would probably work, but I'm very curious why this issue occurs in the first place.